# Prevent menu height from changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Anoying :/]

So I have this menu. As you can see, when I click the menu button, the menu height changes. I'd just like the menu to kinda slide out. (Includes Bootstrap and jQuery) Is it something that can be fixed in CSS or do I have to change my Script for it?

JavaScript:

```js
var main = function(){
    var menuwidth = $(".menu").width();
    $(".menu").width(0).hide();
    $("#menubar").click(function(){
        $(".menu").show();
        if($(".menu").width() === 0){
            $(".menu").animate({
                width: menuwidth
            }, menuwidth*10);
        $(".menu").show();
        }else{
        $(".menu").animate({
            width: 0
            }, menuwidth*10, function(){$(".menu").hide();});
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="nav">
    <center><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify" id="menubar"></i>
    <div class="menu">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">iFone</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">iFatch</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">FOS 9</button>
    </div>
    </center>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.nav{
    background-color: #494949;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align:center;
}

#menubar{
    color:white;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.menubutton{
    font-size: 50;
}
.menu{
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: what is the particular jquery or bootstrap navbar library?

Comment: Are you asking how to animate the sliding of the menu?  JQuery can do that in .animate(), your just not specifying a time it needs to take...  (http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: I won't fix your problem but the center tag was depriciated in HTML 4: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the with with no regard to height. Basically As you reduce the width, the height is increased to accomodate the content.

Set a height for the menu with `overflow:hidden` to hide excess content

```
.menu 
{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px; /*Change this to what fits best*/
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Alternatively use `white-space:nowrap;` to stop the buttons from dropping to the next line

```
.menu 
{
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cooperating with @Jon P answer you could remove center html tag adding the margins with auto

```
.menu
{
...
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```